# combinatorial nullstellensatz proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have a question in the proof of Combinatorial Nullstellensatz given in http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf

Define $t_i=|S_i |-1$ for all $i$,

Assume that $f(x_1,…,x_n )=0$, for every $(x_1,….,x_n )∊S_1× S_2×…×S_n$

They write polynomial 
$g_i (x_i)=∏_{s∊S_i}(x_i -s)= x_i^{t_i+1}- {∑_{j=0}^{t_i}}g_{ij} x_i^j $

I'm not sure how they decomposed $g_i (x_i)$ Any explanation on that will be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $t_i+1$ terms in the product, so multiplying it out, you get the first term $x_i^{t_i+1}$ plus terms of lower order with coefficients which they denote as $g_{ij}$.